# Poor performance for calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors on GPU

Tags: c++, cuda, linear-algebra, gpgpu

In some code we need to get auto vectors and auto values for the generalized eigenvalue problem with symmetric real matrices (Ax=lamba Bx). This code uses DSPGVX from LACPACK. We wanted to speed it up on GPU using a MAGMA function. We asked on this forum and got the answer about this

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/docs/zhegvx_8cpp.html

The size of our matrices (N) goes from 100 to 50000 and even more, related to the number of atoms in a molecule. We observe:

a) for N bigger than 2500 (approx), MAGMA just does not work; segmentation fault
b) MAGMA runs always slower than LAPACK sequential, around 10 times slower

Is this behavior normal and could we overcome it? Can anybody report any reference where anybody working on this similar problems gets a decent speedup?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"...does it not run? Does it produce the wrong results, does it crash and burn at runtime?

Comment: What GPU are you running this on?

Comment: Tesla c2070 with 4gb ram

Comment: N is 50000 and you want an NxN matrix? For floats: 50000 * 50000 * 4 Byte > 4 GByte.

Comment: yes, I agree, but what with N=500 ??

Comment: Are you talking about sparse matrices? I mean, 50K x 50K looks really terrifically complex problem. But if you talk about sparse matrice (i.e. most of the elements are zero) - the algorithms implemented is software may solve it by appropriate means

Comment: Regardless of dense or sparse, _N_ > 2500 should be doable.

Comment: Err DSPGVX is a real valued eigenvalue solver, but ZHGEVX is a *complex* eigenvalue solver. Are you sure you know what you are doing here?

Comment: ZHGEVX is the only thing that can help solve my problem; there is no other thing on GPU for the general eigenvalue problem (otherwise, please tell me). It is designated for complex, but of course, can be used for real

Comment: matrix are dense in all the cases

Comment: So can you clarify which serial lapack routine you are comparing performance with?

Comment: You might be interested in this research: http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~lessig/mrrr/index.html

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a GPU and would use ARPACK

Comment: @harrism; that is not for the generalized symmetric real eigenvalue problem

Comment: @David; that looks really good, I am going to test it, you should change your comment to asnwer

Comment: Link in this question is dead. Please include as much info as possible in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience you may be able to gain greater performance benefits by switching to a better eigensolver. The best solver that I know of is [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/). You will gain most benefit it your matrices have some structure, for example if they are sparse. This solver is also most efficient if you only need to extract a small fraction of the total number of eigenpairs.

I would start off by trying this solver on your problems running just on the CPU. You may find that this alone gives sufficient performance for your needs. If not then it is relatively easy to move the calculation core for ARPACK to the GPU. Or, there are parallel versions of ARPACK available.

Comment: do you think ARPACK can be applied to the case of dense matrices? IF so, could you point to some example? thanks

Comment: It makes no assumptions on the type of matrices. Read about the reverse passing interface and you will understand why this is so.

Comment: you deserve to win the bounty, not only because your inspiring answer but also given your excellent picture, thanks

Comment: Ha ha. You really gave a big laugh there! ;-) Did you give arpack a go yet? Any luck with it. I found it pretty tricky to get on top of but once I got it working its performance blew me away.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried CULA  http://www.culatools.com/ ? CULA is Lapack converted for CUDA by NVIDIA, so at least in theory it should have one of the best implementation for the generalized eigenvalue problem. I think the single precision version is free so you could give it a try.

Comment: I had a look but I did not see any information related with implementations of the generalized eigenvalue problem. Only information about the simple eigenvalue problem is reported there, am I right?

Comment: @flow You are right. I've used CULA only for solving a symmetric eigenvalue problem not for the generalized problem. Sorry the misunderstanding.